# $locale service: get decimal separator (and other locale information)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, locale

I had a look at the angular $locale and according to documentation it does only provide an id (which is `languageId-countryId`). What would be nice was a way to get more specific information as for example the decimal separator character. How can I access this information? Is there another service providing this information? I would like to be able to use the information in a custom directive.

What is the idea behind? Or are the object defined in the locales files only available internally? I mean the locale objects described in files like this: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/i18n/angular-locale_en-us.js

I could not find the real implementation of $locale in the angular source code, can you tell me where it is? Would the possibility to access properties of the locale object be a new feature or does it already exist?

This question is about the current angular 1.x and not 2.x

**Edit**

A feature request to have this information in the public api has been opened [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13289).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$locale already has the information you mention.

Try this Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3dSSAq5pVH1TGS6Hx06L?p=preview

```
app.run(function($locale, $log){
  $log.log('decimal sep: ' + $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP);
});
```

The problem here is that this is not in the "public API" so it'll be up to you to keep this dependency.